# Cannot load R2jags because rjags is not found

Tags: r, jags, r2jags

Cannot for the life of me get R2jags to run. I have tried all different versions of rjags, JAGS, R... each time I get the same error:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags'
All of the other files in the R2jags package loads just fine...

Comment: have you run `install.packages("rjags")`?

Comment: Yes, this prompts the exact same error.

Comment: Did you try the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33069892/6455166

Comment: Yes. Have tried each JAGS version, having all of them installed at the same time, and each installed separately. All I get is this:

Comment: Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: packageVersion(pkg, lib)
  error: package ‘rjags’ not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’